# Observing the changes in input and updating an output in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I want to observe the changes in an `input`. When the `input` changes, the `output` should be updated.

```
    output = reactiveValues(a = 10)
    input = reactiveValues(act1 = 0, act2 = 0)
    eventReactive(input$act1, { output$a = 20 })
    eventReactive(input$act2, { output$a = 30 })
    isolate(input$act1)
    # 0
    isolate(output$a)
    # 10
    input$act1 = 1
    isolate(output$a)
    # 10
    isolate(input$act1)
    # 1
```

I was expecting that `output$a` was going to become 20 after changing `input$act1`. But this didn't occur.

Since `input` is a reactive value object, it should call the reactive expression object returned by `eventReactive`. Why did `output$a` not get updated?

Answer (score 2):

`eventReactive` indeed returns a reactive expression which is a function and is lazily evaluated. There are two conditions that have be met for a reactive expression to be evaluated:

- there have to be an output element which depends on it
- at least one of its dependencies has to be invalidated

Since your code immediately discards newly created expressions it is obvious that are no dependent values and there is no reason for evaluation.

As far as I understand your intentions what you need is an observer which, unlike reactive expression, is eagerly evaluated.

```
observeEvent(somevent, { someAction() })
```

On a side note using reactive expressions for side effects is generally speaking not a good practice.